# perl forking the process inside the if statement executes both the blocks

Tags: perl, fork

When I fork a new process inside the `if` condition, surprisingly both `if` and `else` block gets executed.
According to the perl [`fork`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) subroutine documentation when we execute the method, it returns either `undef`, `PID` depending on whether the fork failed, succeeded respectively.

Below is the code where both the blocks are getting executed.

```perl
if(my $a = fork ) {
  say "if block"; 
} else {
  say "else block";
}
```

> output:
>   if block
>   else block

Where as if I return those manually only one block gets executed depending on whether i return 0 or 1.

```perl
sub a { 1; }

if(my $a = a ) { 
  say "if block"; 
} else {
  say "else block";
}
```

> output:
>   if block

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Thanks @Сухой27. My doubt is clear now.

Comment: `say "else block";` gets executed by fork, and `say "if block";` by main process.Both of them share the same `STDOUT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *According to the perl `fork` subroutine documentation when we execute the method, it returns either `undef`, `PID` depending on whether the fork failed, succeeded respectively.*

Not quite. It actually says the following:

> It returns the child pid to the parent process, `0` to the child process, or undef if the fork is unsuccessful.

So,

- In the parent process, `fork` returns the child's PID, so the parent process outputs `if block`.
- In the child process, `fork` returns `0`, so the child process outputs `else block`.

By checking the value returned, you can have the parent and child do different things.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to see what's happening if you also output the process ID (the `$$` special variable) with each `say` statement:

```
use v5.10;

if( fork ) {
  say "$$ (parent): if block";
} else {
  say "$$ (child): else block";
}
```

You'd then see that you get outputs from two different processes:

```
19997 (parent): if block
20024 (child): else block
```

Typically, the parent process continues and does its thing while the child process continues and does whatever work you wanted to offload. However, the child inherits the standard filehandles of the parent, so the output goes to the same place. If you don't want that, you can immediately change standard output (and others) in the child (or parent, I guess):

```
use v5.10;

if( fork ) {
  say "$$ (parent): if block";
} else {
  say "$$ (child): else block";
  open STDOUT, ...
}
```

If you wanted the current process to turn into something else (so that you still only had one process), look at [exec](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html).